# Determining if a float has a fractional part?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

Here is the problem: The game Totals can be played by any number of people. It starts with a total of 100 and each player in turn makes an integer displacement between -20 and 20 to that total. The winner is the player whose adjustment makes the total equal to 5. Using only the three variables given:
total
adjustment
counter
Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int counter=0;
    float adj;
    int ttl=100;

    printf("You all know the rules now lets begin!!!\n\n\nWe start with 100. What is\n");

    while (ttl!=5)
    {
        printf("YOUR ADJUSTMENT?");
        scanf("%f",&adj);
        counter++;
        if (adj<=20 && adj>=-20)
        {
            ttl=ttl+adj;
            printf("The total is %d\n",ttl);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("I'm sorry. Do you not know the rules?\n");
        }
    }
    printf("The game is won in %d steps!",counter);

}
```

What I need:
When a decimal number is entered it goes to the else. How do I determine if a float has a fractional part.

Comment: At a binary level no floating point numbers have a decimal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Comment: We're talking about floats here. It always "has a decimal". Use a `double` instead. (FYI @Chris and I mean the same)

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: What difference does `double` make?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Everyone has always told me that the difference between a double and a float is that a float has precision errors while a double allows you to store less data. Correct me if I am wrong though.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: A `double` indeed has more precision than a `float`.  I don't see how that's relevant to the question, though.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is there a `float` in that programme at all? There are only integers involved.

Comment: I put a float in so it doesn't automatically round it.

Comment: Checking user input is a difficult task with the primitive libc functions like scanf. For the purpose of a homework assignment, using `float adj; int ok = scanf("%d",&adj); if (ok == 1) { ... }` would have been perfectly fine.  It is not robust for the real world, because it doesn't see the difference between "5" and "5xxx" from the user.  That said, if you *really* wanted to make sure that the user typed in a nice integer and nothing else, then you should use `gets()` and then `stdtol` and make sure that stdtol returns a pointer that points to the end of the string. Anything else is an error.

Answer (score 26):

You can cast the `float` to an `int` and then compare it to your original variable. If they are the same there was no fractional part.

By using this method, there is no need for a temporary variable or a function call.

```
  float adj;

  ....     

  if (adj == (int)adj)
    printf ("no fractional!\n");
  else
    printf ("fractional!\n");
```

---

**Explanation**

Since an `int` cannot handle fractions the value of your `float` will be truncated into an `int` (as an example `(float)14.3` will be truncated into `(int)14`).

When comparing `14` to `14.3` it's obvious that they are not the same value, and therefore "fractional!" will be printed.

Comment: You don't need the explicit cast back to `float`, it'll get cast automatically.  Your solution isn't wrong, I'd just have written it as `f == (int)f`, which I find easier to read and understand.

Comment: @Kevin I edited that at the same time you wrote your comment, I then added some more information regarding the matter, thanks.

Comment: I'm not convinced all the answers that use this technique are robust.  If `adj` is actually the result of an intermediate calculation, it may be held in an extended-precision register.  So the comparison may return `false`, even though when `adj` is later inspected, it actually turns out to be an integer value.

Comment: Are you entirely sure that this works? 14 as a float number will really be represented by around 13.9999239894. So comparison will fail most of the time.

Comment: Mind boggling that this answer has 26 up votes!!! This DOES NOT WORK!

Comment: @tothphu small integers are represented exactly by `float` and `double` if the float and double are IEEE (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442685/can-a-ieee-754-real-number-cover-all-integers-within-its-range).  This is true up to 2^24, which is a really big number, but not the same as the range of `uint32`.  `14` is stored as `14` exactly. Where things go inaccurate are fractions.  `0.1` is not exactly stored as `0.1` because it involves division by 5 which is not a power of 2.

Answer (score 16):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
  float param, fractpart, intpart;

  param = 3.14159265;
  fractpart = modff (param , &intpart);
  return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/modf/

`modff` finds the fractional part, so I guess testing whether it's equal to `0` or `null` will answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to know whether a real number `x` has no fractional part, try `x==floor(x)`.

Comment: @sarnold, not in this case, no. Integers that can be represented as `float` or `double` are represented exactly and `floor` makes no mistake with those that aren't.

Comment: I'm not convinced all the answers that use this technique are robust.  If `adj` is actually the result of an intermediate calculation, it may be held in an extended-precision register.  So the comparison may return `false`, even though when `adj` is later inspected, it actually turns out to be an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Using `scanf()` is problematic.  If the user typed `-5 +10 -15 -15` on the first line of input, then hit return, you'd process the 4 numbers in turn with `scanf()`.  This is likely not what you wanted.  Also, of course, if the user types `+3 or more`, then the first conversion stops once the space is read, and all subsequent conversions fail on the `o` or `or`, and the code goes into a loop.  You must check the return value from `scanf()` to know whether it was able to convert anything.

The read-ahead problems are sufficiently severe that I'd go for the quasi-standard alternative of using `fgets()` to read a line of data, and then using `sscanf()` (that extra `s` is all important) to parse a number.

To determine whether a floating point number has a fractional part as well as an integer part, you could use the [`modf()` or `modff()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/modf.html) function - the latter since your `adj` is a `float`:

```
#include <math.h>

double modf(double x, double *iptr);
float modff(float value, float *iptr);
```

The return value is the signed fractional part of `x`; the value in `iptr` is the integer part.  Note that `modff()` may not be available in compilers (runtime libraries) that do not support C99.  In that case, you may have to use `double` and `modf()`.  However, it is probably as simple to restrict the user to entering integers with `%d` format and an integer type for `adj`; that's what I'd have done from the start.

Another point of detail: do you really want to count invalid numbers in the total number of attempts?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int counter=0;
    int ttl=100;

    printf("You all know the rules now lets begin!!!\n"
           "\n\nWe start with 100. What is\n");

    while (ttl != 5)
    {
        char  buffer[4096];
        float a_int;
        float adj;

        printf("YOUR ADJUSTMENT?");
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == 0)
            break;
        if (sscanf("%f", &adj) != 1)
            break;
        if (adj<=20 && adj>=-20 && modff(adj, &a_int) == 0.0)
        {
            counter++;  // Not counting invalid numbers
            ttl += adj;
            printf("The total is %d\n", ttl);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("I'm sorry. Do you not know the rules?\n");
        }
    }

    if (ttl == 5)
        printf("The game is won in %d steps!\n", counter);
    else
        printf("No-one wins; the total is not 5\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Clearly, I'm studiously ignoring the possibility that someone might type in more than 4095 characters before typing return.

Answer (score 1):

I am only learning C so tell me if I am wrong, please.

But if instead of using

```
scanf("%f",&adj);
```

if you use:

```
scanf("%d%d", &adj, &IsUndef);
```

Therefore if the user typed anything other than a whole integer &IsUndef would not equal NULL and must have a fractional part sending the user to else.

maybe.