# Does IEEE 754 guarantee exact representation for operations on whole numbers that fit in mantissa?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

From what I can gather, whole numbers that can be fit in the mantissa of a floating point number are represented exactly:

[Can a IEEE 754 real number "cover" all integers within its range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442685/can-a-ieee-754-real-number-cover-all-integers-within-its-range)

My question is:

- Given 2 floating point whole numbers that are exactly represented,
- does an operation (+,-,/,*) on the 2 numbers always produce an exactly represented floating point number
- so long as the result is in the exactly representable range?

In other words, is there ever a time when floating point 2.0 * 3.0 != 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this falls out from the requirement that the basic operations are correctly rounded.  Since the result is exactly representable it is also the correctly rounded result.